# CRM 2011 Workflow condition to check fields in another entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have to create a workflow that if a user is out of the office all tasks assigned to that user are then assigned to an alternate user. I have added fields to the user form, leave date, return date and alternate user. I somehow need to view these fields so that if a task is assigned to the user, it first checks to see if the leave data is in effect and if so then assigns the task to the alternate user. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a workflow for Task that triggers on Create and Assign and has these two steps:

If ExecutionTime is greater than Task.Owner.LeaveDate AND ExecutionTime is less than Task.Owner.ReturnDate

Assign Task to Task.Owner.AlternateUser